# Testing livedata with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, android-livedata

I have following test that checks if activity correctly gets data from repository through viewmodel.

```
@Config(application = TestApplication::class)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
class BusinessTests {
    private lateinit var viewModel: BusinessCollectionViewModel
    private lateinit var activity: BusinessCollectionVerticalActivity
    private lateinit var observer: Observer<Triple<NetworkState, PagedList<Edge<Business>>, TimeTracking?>>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        observer = mock()
    }

    @Test
    fun givenBusinessMock_whenVerticalCollection_thenBusinessVerticalWith2Items() {

        val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(BusinessCollectionVerticalActivity::class.java)
        activityScenario.onActivity {
            activity = it
        }

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity)[BusinessCollectionViewModel::class.java]

        viewModel.data.observeForever(observer)
        assert(viewModel.data.value?.second?.size == 2)
    }
}
```

Problem is that the test always fails, but in debug it passes correctly, but when I debug it with false condition in assert, following exception pops up.

```
java.lang.Exception: Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test failure. You might need a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call.
```

It's really strange behaviour and I don't know what to do. And of course I tried to add shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() before observe.

I'm using latest robolectric 4.3, could it be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the thread that runs the UI test is finishing without any errors while the `assert` is running in a different thread.

You can change your test method to hold the thread until it's release by the thread that runs the observeOnce:

```
@Test
fun givenBusinessMock_whenVerticalCollection_thenBusinessVerticalWith2Items() {

    val syncObject = Object()

    val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(BusinessCollectionVerticalActivity::class.java)
    activityScenario.onActivity {
        activity = it
    }

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity)[BusinessCollectionViewModel::class.java]

    viewModel.data.observeOnce {
        assert(it.second.size == 2)

        synchronized (syncObject) {
            syncObject.notify()
        }
    }

    synchronized (syncObject) {
        syncObject.wait()
    }
}
```

If you want a better approach, you can observeForever in your data and check the value:

```
var observer: Observer<?> // replace ? by your type
viewModel.data.observeForever(observer)
assert(viewModel.data.value.second.size == 2)
```

More info in this [article](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-architecture-components-testing-your-viewmodel-livedata-70177af89c6e).

Comment: First solution didn't work, second only partly. When I run test, it falls on assertion failed, because viewModel.data.value is null. When I debug it, viewModel.data.value.second.size is 2 so that is correct, but when I change assert condition to fail, exception I mentioned in first post with main looper showed. Do you have any idea what to do? Thanks

Comment: where are you placing the `assert` with the second approach? can you update the question with the code?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it using the **instantTaskExecutorRule**.

You need to add the following dependency to your app buil.gradle file:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

And include the following rule in your tests:

```
// Executes tasks in the Architecture Components in the same thread
@get:Rule
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Comment: That could be it + rxjava immediate scheduler. But I can't say for certain, because I ditched robolectric completely and only use unit tests, but with those rules.

Comment: I found that fix in Google's iosched project: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/main/mobile/src/test/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/LaunchViewModelTest.kt.